# $C^\infty_0$ approximation of $L^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sequence-of-function

I have recently proven that $C_0^\infty (\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p (\Omega)$ for $1\leq p < \infty$.
It is known that  $C_0^\infty (\Omega)$ isnt dense in $L^\infty (\Omega)$.
However there is a sequence with following properties for $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$:

1: $||u_n||_{L^\infty} \leq ||u||_{L^\infty}$

2: $u_n \rightharpoonup^\star u$ in $L^\infty (\Omega)$

3: $u_n \rightarrow u$  almost everywhere in $\Omega$

I got the tip that to approximate $\Omega$ with 
$\Omega_n = \left\{x\in\Omega|\operatorname{dist}(x, \partial \Omega) > \frac{2}{n}, |x|<n \right\}$.

Now i take the $\xi_n = \chi_{\Omega_n}$ and the Dirac sequence $\rho_n$
and define 
$$v_n = \rho_n \star (\xi_n u)$$
I have to find a subsequence of that that works with the 3 properties.
Can anyone help me find these subsequence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked if the sequence satisfies any of the three properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223632/are-smooth-functions-with-compact-support-weakly-dense-in-l-infty

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki How? I dont see how that would help me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @SquareJoe use the same approach as in the comments of my answer: take $v_{n,m} = \rho_n \star (\xi_m u)$. then as $m \to \infty$, $v_{n,m}$ converges $L^1(\Omega_n)$ to $u$, so there is a subsequence $v_{n,m_k}$ convering almost everywhere on $\Omega_n$ to $u$. now consider $u_n=v_{n,m_n}$

Comment: Okay but how does that suffice 1), which means ||vn,m||<||v||

Comment: @SquareJoe $|\xi_{m} u |  \leq |u|$ for all $m$, and $\| \rho_n \star h \| \leq \| h\|$ for any $h$. so $\|v_{n,m}\| \leq \| u \|$ for all $m,n$